# Octave: Plotting results of 3D interpolation

Tags: plot, octave, interpolation

I want to plot a surface whose elevation is the result of 3D interpolation on scattered data:
I have coordinates x, y, z and the scalar value v in three column vectors. I would like to interpolate v on, say, a constant x plane with coordinates xi, yi, zi obtaining vi and eventually plot the surface (yi,zi,vi).
How can I do that?

Comment: Check this for starters: https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Three_002dDimensional-Plots.html.  I think you should try something, and if you don't figure it out, revise the question to show what you've tried.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. In fact, I have been reading the manual and searching similar examples on the Internet many times before posting my question. I think I managed to solve it today, with the help of some friends and asking on the #octave irc channel too. Here comes the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here comes the solution I have found, thanks to andy1978 on #octave irc channel and Nicola:

```
x1 = linspace (min(x),max(x),50) ;
y1 = linspace (min(y),max(y),50) ;
z1 = linspace (min(z),max(z),50) ;
[xx, yy, zz] = meshgrid (x1, y1, z1) ;

vv = griddata3 (x, y, z, v, xx, yy, zz ) ;

x0 = 0.05 ;   % constant x of chosen plane

[~,i] = min (abs (x - x0)) ;

vv_sect = vv (:, i, :) ;      % here I slice the matrix of interpolated results at x=x0
vv_out = squeeze (vv_sect) ;  % and this is what I needed to reduce the dimensionality of
                              % the sliced matrix

[yy2,zz2] = meshgrid (y1, z1) ;

surf (yy2, zz2, vv_out ) ;
```